# CoffeeScript set property in Class during callback

Tags: coffeescript

Here is my CoffeeScript class

```
class HotsauceQS
    err: null

    constructor: (@obj, @qUrl) ->

    sendMsg: ->
        sqs.sendMessage
          MessageBody: JSON.stringify(@obj)
          QueueUrl: @qURL
        , @handleResponse

    handleResponse: (err, data) =>
        @err = err if err?

module.exports = HotsauceQS
```

I can't get the `@err` property to set:

```
h = require('./hotsaucesqs')
m = new h obj, url
m.sendMsg()

console.log m.err # this is undefined :(
```

Comment: why should it be defined? are you sure that your @handleRespone refers to the right `this`? what `sendMessage` is that? If it is asyncronous, it can't work. Look up how asyncronous libraries work.

Comment: have you tried to log out your arguments from the callback? are you sure that err is getting passed back?